# "game must be in the same directory" error using wine

Tags: 12.04, wine

I installed wine 1.6 on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and downloaded project IGI 1. However, by right clicking and opening it with wine windows program loader, I get an error saying `game must be in the same directory`.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the game folder to your `~/.wine/drive_c` directory. To do this, open nautilus and press <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to reveal hidden folders and files. After this, copy the complete folder of the program you are trying to run using wine. Now, go to your home folder(where you have your Documents, Downloads directory by default) and here you will find a `.wine` directory, open the directory and paste the folder in the `drive_c` folder and try to run it again.